# Emacs ruby-mode indent private

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs

Does anyone know how to get ruby-mode in Emacs to indent all definitions under private? Here's an example:

```
def redirect_back_or(default)    
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)    
    clear_return_to  
end 

private

    def user_from_remember_token      
        User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)    
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private doesn't introduce a new scope, so indenting definitions under it is not technically correct. While there are several [indentation styles for private/protected members](http://fabiokung.com/2010/04/05/ruby-indentation-for-access-modifiers-and-their-sections/), the only one supported by ruby-mode is the one that is semantically correct (doesn't introduce additional nesting). The ["Ruby style guide"](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) also recommends that style (not to mention a two 2 space indentation).

That all being said - there's no way to customize this aspect of `ruby-mode`.

Comment: Even though this may not be the official style, Michael Hartl suggested doing it this way in his book. He brought up an experience where he spent a few hours debugging because one of his methods was unintentionally included in private. I didn't take his advice seriously until the same thing happened to me =[

Comment: This might be so, but Michael Hartl is hardly as influential as Matz and I doubt that Matz and the core Ruby devs would ever approve of such an indentation that doesn't correspond to the code semantics.

Comment: Whether or not some Big-Name Hacker approves or disapproves of an indentation style is not the issue here. Instead, it is getting the indentation to work **according to the poster's individual preference.**